# What is the difference between find with -exec and xargs?

Tags: command-line, find, xargs

trying to learn Bash scripting I want to execute some command on all files below my current directory that satisfy a certain condition. Using

```
find -name *.flac
```

Specifically I want to convert `.flac` to `.mp3`. I can find all the files. However I do not see the difference in executing a command using either the option `-exec` for `find` and using `xargs`. E.g.

```
find -name *.flac | xargs -i ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3
```

compared to

```
find -name *.flac -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3 \;
```

Can someone point out the difference? What is better praticice? What are the advantages/ disadvantages?

Also: If I wanted to simultaneously delete the original file, how would I add a second command in the above code?

Comment: Nice discussion here https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary

Comment: And you don't seem to understand quoting. `echo find -name *.flac ` vs `echo file -name '*.flac'` to see how quoting can be used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Summary:

Unless you are much more familiar with `xargs` than `-exec`, you will probably want to use `-exec` when you use `find`.

Since `xargs` is a separate program, calling it is likely to be marginally less efficient than using `-exec`, which is a feature of the `find` program. We don't usually want to call an extra program if it doesn't provide any additional benefit in terms of reliability, performance or readability. Since `find ... -exec ...` provides the ability to run commands with an argument list (as `xargs` does) if possible, there is not really any advantage of using `xargs` with `find` over `-exec`. In the case of `ffmpeg`, we have to specify input and output files, so we can't make performance gains using either method to construct an argument list, and with `xargs` removing the illogical original filename extension is more difficult.

#### What `xargs` does

<sub>**Note:** The verbose flag (which prints the constructed command with its arguments) in `xargs` is `-t`, and the interactive flag (which causes the user to be prompted for confirmation to operate on each argument) is `-p`. You may find both of these useful for understanding and testing its behaviour.</sub>

`xargs` attempts to turn its STDIN (typically the STDOUT of the previous command that has been piped to it) into a list of arguments to some command.

```
command1 | xargs command2 [output of command1 will be appended here]
```

Since STDOUT or STDIN is just a stream of text (this is also why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`), `xargs` is easily tripped up. It reads arguments as being delimited by spaces or newlines. Filenames are allowed to contain spaces and may even contain newlines, and such filenames will cause unexpected behaviour. Let's say you have a file called `foo bar`. When a list containing this filename is piped to `xargs`, it attempts to run the given command on `foo` and on `bar`.

The same problem occurs when you type `command foo bar`, and you know you can avoid it by quoting the space or the whole name, eg `command foo\ bar` or `command "foo bar"`, but even if we are able to quote the list passed to `xargs` we don't usually want to, because we don't want the whole list to be treated as a single argument. The standard solution to this is to use the null character as delimiter, since filenames cannot contain it:

```
find path test(s) -print0 | xargs -0 command
```

This causes `find` to append the null character to each filename instead of a space, and `xargs` to treat only the null character as delimiter.

Problems may still occur if the command doesn't accept multiple arguments or if the argument list is extremely long.

In this case you are using `ffmpeg`, which expects input files to be specified first, and output files to be specified last. We can tell `ffmpeg` which files(s) to use as input explicitly with the `-i` flag, but we need to give the output filename (from which the format is usually guessed, though we can also specify it) too. So, to construct suitable commands, you need to use the replace string option (`-I` or `-i`) of `xargs` to specify both the input and output files:

```
... | xargs -I{} command {} {}.out
```

(the documentation says that `-i` is deprecated for this purpose and we should use `-I` instead, but I am not sure why. When using `-I`, you must specify the replacement (`{}` is normally used) immediately after the option. With `-i` you can omit to specify the replacement, but `{}` is understood by default.)

The `-I` option causes the command list to be split only on newlines, not spaces, so if you are sure your filenames will not contain newlines, you do not have to use `-print0 | xargs -0` when you use `-I`. If you are uncertain, you can still use the safer syntax:

```
find -name "*.flac" -print0 | xargs -0I{} ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3
```

However, the performance benefit of `xargs` (which enables us to run a command once with a list of arguments) is lost here, since `ffmpeg` must be run once for each pair of input and output files (you can see this easily by prepending `echo` to `ffmpeg` to test the above command). This also produces an illogical filename and doesn't allow you to run multiple commands. To do the latter, you can call `bash`, as in [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/959052/527764):

```
... | xargs -I{} bash -c 'ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3 && rm {}'
```

but renaming [is tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803296/modifying-replace-string-in-xargs).

#### How `-exec` is different

When you use the `-exec` option to `find`, the found files are passed as **arguments** to the command after `-exec`. They aren't turned into text. With the syntax:

```
find ... -exec command {} \;
```

*`command`* is run once for each file found. With the syntax

```
find ... -exec command {} +
```

an argument list is constructed from the found files so that we can run the command only once (or only as many times as required) on multiple files, giving the performance benefit provided by `xargs`. However, since the filename arguments aren't constructed from a stream of text, using `-exec` doesn't have the problem `xargs` has of breaking on spaces and other special characters.

With `ffmpeg`, we can't use `+` for the same reason as `xargs` didn't give any performance benefit; since we need to specify both input and output, the command must be run on each file individually. We have to use some form of

```
find -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.out \;
```

This, again, will give you a rather illogically named file, as [dessert's answer explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/959052/527764), so you may want to strip it, as dessert's answer explains how to do with string manipulation (not easily done in `xargs`; another reason to use `-exec`). It also explains how to run multiple commands on the file so that you can safely remove the original file after a successful conversion.

Instead of repeating dessert's recommendation, which I agree with, I will suggest an alternative to `find`, which allows similar flexibility to running `bash -c` after `-exec`; a bash `for` loop:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar           # allow recursive globbing with **
for f in ./**/*.flac; do    # for all files ending with .flac
   # convert them, stripping the original extension from the new filename
   echo ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.flac}.mp3" &&
   echo rm -v "$f"          # if that succeeded, delete the original
done
shopt -u globstar           # turn recursive globbing off
```

Remove the `echo`es after testing to actually operate on the files.

`ffmpeg` doesn't recognise `--` to mark the end of options, so to avoid filenames beginning with `-` being interpreted as options, we use `./` to indicate the current directory instead of starting with `**`, so that all paths begin with `./` instead of arbitrary filenames. This means we don't need to use `--` with `rm` (which does recognise it) either.

---

**Note**: you should quote your `-name` test expression if it contains any wildcard characters, otherwise the shell will expand them if possible (ie if they match any files in the current directory) before they are passed to `find`, so in the first place, use

```
find -name "*.flac"
```

to prevent unexpected behaviour.

Comment: That's an excellent answer, thank you so much! OP posed a second question which you didn't address so far: *If I wanted to simultaneously delete the original file, how would I add a second command in the above code?*

Comment: @dessert thank you & thank you for pointing that out :) Since your answer gives the best way with `find` imho, I added an alternative to run multiple commands

Comment: **"if it doesn't provide any additional benefit in terms of [...] performance"**: That is where I would like to throw in `xargs -P` which I use very frequently to speed up things a lot and which to my knowledge is not possible with `-exec`.

Comment: @RoVo that's interesting - I hope you feel like adding an answer about it :)

Comment: +1 for the `+` syntax! Not covered in most basic `find` examples. In a task I just ran using `stat` on a large number of files, I get about a 300x speedup with `+` over `\;`.

Answer (score 4):

Generally one tries to call as few commands as possible, but in your case I think its a matter of taste – I'd go with `-exec`, using it like so:

```
find . -name '*.flac' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" "${0%flac}mp3" && rm "$0"' {} \;
```

The trick is to call `bash` with the `-c` option, this way you can not only execute multiple commands but also use [Bash Parameter Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove the `flac` ending from your filenames – I suppose you don't really want to end up with files named *filename.flac.mp3*, do you?

#### Explanations

- `bash -c '…' {}` – run the command(s) `…` in `bash` with the filename as the first argument (accessible with `$0`)
- `${0%flac}` – strip `flac` from the end of the filename
- `&& rm "$0"` – only if the preceding command succeeded, remove the original file

Answer (score 4):

As Zanna and dessert already answered `-exec` should be preferred when `xargs` is not necessary (*"We don't usually want to call an extra program if it doesn't provide any additional benefit in terms of reliability, performance or readability."*)

While that is totally correct I want to add that `xargs` in combination with the `-P` flag can provide a substantial benefit in terms of **performance**.

`xargs` will spawn the processes in parallel enabling multi-threading, similar to but more flexible than the `parallel` command.

```
-P max-procs, --max-procs=max-procs
              Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.  Use the -n option or the -L option with -P; other‐
              wise chances are that only one exec will be done. 
              [...]
```

This especially helps with with processes that do not run multi-threaded by themselves. In your case `ffmpeg` will take care about multithreading, so it won't help or will even have a negative effect on performance.

```
find . -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 -i -P 20 command -in {} -out {}.out
```

Comment: Be careful with `-P`! Running `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P0 stat --terse`, I get *almost* correct output, but some lines are slightly garbled -- presumably due to race conditions? My output is fixed with `| xargs -0 -n1 -P0 stat --terse`, but the `-n1` flag kills all the advantage of `-P` and then some. In this application, I'm better off with `xargs -0` (no `-P` and no `-n1`).