# find: paths must precede expression: )xargs

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, find, xargs

```
mkdir dregsfolder
find /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/ -maxdepth 1 -not \( -type d -or -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.gif" -or -iname "*.docx" \)xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty mv /home/tony/Desktop/dregsfolder
```

When I run that code; I am advised

```
find: paths must precede expression: )xargs
```

I am confused as I thought that the path had already been specified with the `/home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files`.

I am further confused, because in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90886/how-can-i-find-files-and-then-use-xargs-to-move-them) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, we have an example `xargs` copying files to a directory called `play`:

```
find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name "x*" | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' ~/play/
```

And here, it seems that the target directory, i.e. play; has been specified AFTER the `xargs`...

I'm wanting clarification as to the precise mechanisms associated with `xargs` and the nuances associated therein, for the parsing of not ONLY a file from a directory (as identiifed in previous question) but furthermore, its wider usage within the unix world in relation to parameters.

Comment: You just forgot half of the line, it's supposed to be `… "*.docx" \) -print0 | xargs -0 …`. Don't just omit crucial commands and options!

Comment: `man mv` states that you may use it like `mv SOURCE DEST` or `mv -t DIRECTORY SOURCE`.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: This is basically https://askubuntu.com/q/974735/507051 again, isn't it? You're neither supposed to post what's basically the same question over and over again nor two questions in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` attempts to construct an argument list from its stdin (standard input). Often, the stdin of `xargs` is the output of some command that has been piped to `xargs`. To create a useless example, we can waste a lot of characters listing the files in our home directory, instead of just typing `ls -A ~` like this:

```
echo ~ | xargs ls -A
```

The pipe operator `|` takes the stdout (standard output) of the command to the left of it, and passes it as the stdin of the command to the right of it. It's important to remember that stdout is just a stream of text, which may cause problems when passed to the second command by `xargs` if it contains spaces or special characters. When we use `find`, whose output is filenames, with `xargs`, to avoid errors caused by special characters, we conventionally use

```
find -print 0 | xargs -0
```

This causes `find` to append the null character to each filename and `xargs` to interpret the list as null-delimited instead of space-delimited. The null character cannot appear in filenames, so there is no chance that a filename will be interpreted as two filenames if we delimit with the null character.

Since you missed out the pipe character `|` that separates and connects the two commands `find` and `xargs`, `find` thought that `)xargs` was one of its arguments, and since it did not begin with `-` or follow a valid test beginning with `-`, it decided that `)xargs` must be a path you want to search, but `paths must precede expression`, the syntax of `find` requires the path to search to be given before other arguments.

Many people prefer to use `-exec` with `find` instead of piping to `xargs` (see [What is the difference between find with -exec and xargs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959024/what-is-the-difference-between-find-with-exec-and-xargs)), for example:

```
find /path -tests ... -exec some_command {} +
```

This may be more suitable in your case, particularly since the `mv` command expects its last argument to be the destination. You could use `xargs -I {} mv {} /path/to/destination` but it would be more readable and perhaps more efficient to specify the destination with `-t`

```
find /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/ -maxdepth 1 -not \( -type d -or -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.gif" -or -iname "*.docx" \) -exec mv -t /home/tony/Desktop/dregsfolder -- {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

"`find: paths must precede expression: )xargs`" is `find`'s way of telling you that, as it was processing its parameters, it saw something that looks like a starting point (actually, it did NOT look like an expression) AFTER it thought it was done parsing paths to search, and it saw the problem around "`)xargs`". `man find` says `find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [starting-point...] [expression]`

You have omitted the pipe (`|`) symbol to connect `find`'s output to `xargs`'s input.

Another point -  Using the "`-0`" option to `xargs` **requires** you to tell find to separate the filenames with `NUL`s, with `-print0` - you don't.

Did you read my answer to [Moving files of specific type/extension from one directory to another?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974735/507051) ?

Comment: I did. :)

I tried to implement it, but it did not work for some reason :\ (I goofed probably)

specifically; the mv command doesn't work:

mv target 'home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/10439__batchku__gbell-8-1-pp.aif"  is not a directory